# Can you help me identify these glowing gold and black patterned wheels in Rocket League?

Tags: rocket-league

Can someone help me identify the following wheel?

[image: Picture of a Rocket League wheel]

I've gone over the list of all the wheels listed at [Rocket League Insider](https://rl.insider.gg/) repeatedly, but they don't seem to be listed there. They could be from [DLC](https://store.steampowered.com/dlc/252950/Rocket_League/), but the DLC don't enumerate their contents specifically. They could also be some kind of [reward](https://rewards.rocketleague.com/), but it wasn't one I was able to find.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This wheel was awarded at the end of Season 9 to those who earned the competitive Gold tier rewards.

[image: Season 9 Rewards]

I don't know their specific name, but that's not going to help you if you were trying to obtain a set. As prizes to competitive events, these can't be traded.

In addition to the sources listed in the question, these are other locations to search to identify Rocket League items:

- [Season 9 rewards](https://www.rocketleague.com/news/rocket-league-roadmap--spring-2019--plus-season-9-rewards/)
- [Season 8 rewards](https://www.rocketleague.com/news/season-8-rewards-season-9-details/)
- [Season 7 rewards](https://www.rocketleague.com/news/season-7-rewards-preview-season-8-details/)
- [Season 6 rewards](https://www.rocketleague.com/news/competitive-season-7-starts-in-february/)
- [Season 5 rewards](https://www.rocketleague.com/news/competitive-season-6-changes-season-5-rewards/)
- [Season 4 rewards](https://www.rocketleague.com/news/competitive-season-4-rewards/)
- [Season 3 rewards](https://www.rocketleague.com/news/competitive-season-4-update-and-season-3-rewards/)
- [Season 2 rewards](https://www.rocketleague.com/news/coming-soon-competitive-season-3-and-season-2-rewards/)
- [Season 1 rewards](https://www.rocketleague.com/news/season-1-rewards--uncommon-items/)

Comment: Commentators / editors: If you disagree with the content of the answer then please downvote it, but please refrain from editing it any further. Thank you.